# How to calculate average value and divide by only available and not include missing

Tags: sas

I have a data set example below, i want to calculate average monthly salary per customer but only divide my average value with only the number of months where the amount value is captured.

```
data have;
infile cards truncover;
input   ID  :$10.  name  :$10.  amount  :10. month :$10. ;
cards;
A1 John 2000   Jan
A1 John          Feb
A1 John 300 Mar
A1 John  2000  Apr
A1 John 300   May
A1 John 200 Jun
A2 Sam       Jan
A2 Sam       Feb
A2 Sam 100 Mar
A2 Sam 300 Apr
A2 Sam 300 May
A2 Sam 300 Jun
A3 Paul 1000 Jan
A3 Paul 1000 Feb
A3 Paul 1000 Mar
A3 Paul      Apr
A3 Paul      May
A3 Paul 1000 Jun
A4 Phil 300 Jan
A4 Phil 300 Feb
A4 Phil 300 Mar
A4 Phil 300 Apr
A4 Phil 300 May
A4 Phil 300 Jun
;
```

What i want to archive is that if we look at ID = A1 there are 5 amount values out of 6, i want to do (2000+300+2000+300+200)/5 = ? for ID=A2 the division will be by 4 since only four are missing

Comment: You will have to provide more information on how you want to 'archive' the results.  Will it be a separate data set with one row per id ? Will you need to append to this other data set ? Will 'archiving' be a new column in the existing data set with the average value for the group being repeated in each row of the group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Proc sql;
     create table want as 
     select distinct ID,
     average(amount) as Calculation 
     from have
     group by ID;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take time to learn about the SAS `MEANS` Procedure and `BY` Statement.

```
Proc means data = have;
  by ID;
  var amount;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL AVG aggregate function does exactly what you wanted

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
    select ID,name,AVG(amount) from have group by ID,name;
quit;
```